# Polyline stopped drawing on my map

Tags: java, android, location, maps, polyline

For some reason my polylines won't draw. I'm not sure what's going on. This is supposed to draw a line based on the location updates of your phone. Any idea?

```
public Boolean isTracking = false;
public String routeID;
public int pointID = 0;
@Override

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lng = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);      //Location declared into a LatLng

    if (isTracking){
        trackRoute(lat, lng, latLng);
    }
}

private void trackRoute(double lat, double lng, LatLng latLng){
    drawLine(latLng);                                                  //call drawline
    database.insertPoint(routeID, pointID, lat, lng);                  //Insert points into database
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 18));
    pointID++;
}
private void drawLine(LatLng latLng){
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions()
            .width(5)
            .color(Color.BLUE)
            .geodesic(true);
            options.add(latLng);

    line = mMap.addPolyline(options);                   //set up options and draw line.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple pass Lat and Lon in drawLine method ,and make drawline method with two parameter.
Replace  `options.add(latLng);` line to `options.add(new LatLng(lat,lng));`

```
 private void trackRoute(double lat, double lng, LatLng latLng){
     drawLine(lat,lng);                                                   
    database.insertPoint(routeID, pointID, lat, lng);                   
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 18));
    pointID++;
}
private void drawLine(double lat, double lng){
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions()
            .width(5)
            .color(Color.BLUE)
            .geodesic(true);
            options.add(new LatLng(lat,lng));

    line = mMap.addPolyline(options);                   
}
```